# Android ReceiveReceive Text via Bluetooth

Tags: android, logging, arduino, android-bluetooth

I try to receive Text via Bluetooth (BT) using Android. I can view the Text using a pre-existing Bluetooth logger from the Google Play store, but with my own code it does not work correct.

In general I use the default BT code from the Android documentation and [samples](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BluetoothChat). I log the received Text. I expect my text to be something like:
`-0.01, -0.03, 1.04`, but I only receive parts of it. Here is a part of the logs:

```
06-14 17:25:01.925 28217-28412/[...]: I read the following: 0.01, -0.
06-14 17:25:01.977 28217-28412/[...]: I read the following: 
06-14 17:25:02.039 28217-28412/[...]: I read the following: -
06-14 17:25:02.051 28217-28412/[...]: I read the following: 0.01, -0.
06-14 17:25:02.101 28217-28412/[...]: I read the following: 
06-14 17:25:02.174 28217-28412/[...]: I read the following: -
```

This is the code I use to read from BT:

```
    public void run() {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];  // buffer store for the stream
        int bytes; // bytes returned from read()

        // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
        while (true) {
            try {
                // Read from the InputStream
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                String readMessage = new String(buffer, 0, bytes);
                Log.e(Constants.TAG, "I read the following: "+readMessage);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Not sure if it's relevant, but I am using an HC-06 BT module connected to an Arduino sending data with `9600` Baud. I can give you the code for this as well.

I tried two different Android phones with the same result. Wiko Fever and Moto G2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the issue. The actual transmission was ok. This was a combination of two things. First I transmitted the data from the Arduino using `Serial.println` which I changed to `Serial.print`. Also I threw the Logging away and sent the results to the UI.

So it seems that the Android Logging Framework is sensible for the new line character that is sent by the Arduino and (partially)skips the Log message as you can see above.